# C++ accessing elements of an object stored in a vector

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

Say for example you have:

```
class Plant {
    public:
    ...public accessors, etc ...

}
```

Then you have a specific plant class:

```
class Broccoli : public Plant
{
    public:
        Broccoli(int i);
        virtual ~Broccoli();

        inline BroccoliSprite* getPlantSprite() { return _plantSprite; };

    private:
         BroccoliSprite* _plantSprite;

};
```

at some point the `Broccoli` object is stored in a vector: `std::vector<Plant> vPlants;`

accessing the vector and its elements I use: `inline std::vector<Plant>& getPlants() { return vPlants; };`

to access:

```
 for (int f=0; f < _f.getPlants().size(); f++)
 {
    Plant _p1 = _f.getPlants().at(f);

    cocos2d::CCSprite* s = _p1.getPlantSprite();
    ....


 }
```

I want to be able to use `getPlantSprite()` to display it to the user but the compiler tells me: `No member named 'getPlantSprite' in 'Plant'`

This is true, but the object in the vector is of type `Plant` and contains a member variable that Is the sprite I need, the getter returns it.

What I dont understand is how get access to `getPlantSprite()`

I guess one thing is I could change `class Plant` to be `class Plant : <some generic object class> and store that object in the vector instead of`Plants`

or I could cast to a `Broccoli`.

UPDATE: So to use `shared_ptr<>`

I am currently doing:

```
 Broccoli b(tempField->getFieldNumber()); 
 tempField->getPlants().push_back(b);
```

This means I would be doing something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Plant> object1(new Broccoli(tempField->getFieldNumber()));
tempField->getPlants().push_back(std::move(object1));
```

How do I now access the `Broccoli` object inside the shared pointer to do things to it?

Before I used to do something like:

```
Broccoli b(tempField->getFieldNumber());

tempField->getFieldSprite()->addChild(b.getPlantSprite(), 2);

b.getPlantSprite()->setRotation(BROCCOLI::plantRotation);

tempField->getPlants().push_back(b);
```

Now:

```
std::shared_ptr<Plant> object1(new Broccoli(tempField->getFieldNumber()));

tempField->getPlants().push_back(std::move(object1));

b.getPlantSprite()->setRotation(BROCCOLI::plantRotation);

tempField->getPlants().push_back(b);
```

Compiler says `b.` is an undeclared identifier which obviously makes sense, but I need to do more to the object after putting it inside the `shared_ptr`

so this might be:

```
std::shared_ptr<Plant> object1(new Broccoli(tempField->getFieldNumber()));

tempField->getPlants().push_back(std::move(object1));

object1->getPlantSprite()->setRotation(BROCCOLI::plantRotation);
```

but the compiler still says: `` `No member named 'getPlantSprite' in 'Plant' ``

UPDATE 2: to avoid object slicing, it looks like making functions in base class pure virtual might help solve this, still using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`

UPDATE 3:

```
for (int f=0; f < _f.getPlants().size(); f++)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Plant> sbas = _f.getPlants().at(f);

    std::shared_ptr<Broccoli> sder2 = std::static_pointer_cast<Broccoli>(sbas);

    .. do stuff with `sder2`
}
```

in this vector there will be things like Broccoli, Asparagus, etc. I will have to use dynamic_pointer_cast, but what does this line look like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Plant> sbas = _f.getPlants().at(f);

std::shared_ptr<Plant?????> sder2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Broccoli>(sbas);
```

I *do* store an `internal ID` as part of Plant that I could do a `switch` on to decide what type to statically cast to.....though.

Comment: You should probably use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead of `new`: `auto b = std::make_shared<Broccoli>(tempField->getFieldNumber());`

Comment: Polymorphism with `shared_ptr`s is analogous to polymorphism with raw pointers, you just have to use [`std::X_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) instead of `X_cast`, like `std::static_pointer_cast` instead of `static_cast`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4187903a19b8aa8) (Note: you'll probably want to use a `dynamic_pointer_cast`)

Comment: are you saying: `std::shared_ptr<Plant> object1(std::make_shared<Broccoli>(tempField->getFieldNumber()));` instead of `std::shared_ptr<Plant> object1(new Broccoli(tempField->getFieldNumber()));`?

Comment: Nope, just `auto object1 = std::make_shared<Broccoli>( tempField->getFieldNumber() );`, see the example above.

Comment: Seems like `unique_ptr`s are more complicated if you want to cast and avoid raw pointers (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002641/dynamic-casting-for-unique-ptr)). You could use a `vector<unique_ptr<Plant>>` and non-owning raw pointers for the casts, if it is otherwise clear in your project that the resulting raw pointers are non-owning.

Comment: Your last example, just above "UPDATE 2", probably invokes Undefined Behaviour (if you made it compile). Moving an object leaves that object in a pretty much undefined state. For `shared_ptr`s, it leaves the moved `shared_ptr` empty (and `shared_ptr::operator->` is `noexcept` but requires the `shared_ptr` to be non-empty). If you need to later access the element which is to be inserted in the vector, either get it anew from the vector (e.g. via `vector::back()`) or store a copy of the `shared_ptr` in the vector (i.e. leave out the `move`).

Comment: I think I am clearer. can you look at Update3?

Comment: so doing what I mentioned in Update3 works.

Comment: "I do store an internal ID as part of Plant that I could do a switch on to decide what type to statically cast to.....though." Yes, you can use a `static_pointer_cast` in this case, it'll also probably be a bit faster than a `dynamic_pointer_cast`. If you wanted to use a `dynamic_pointer_cast`, just replace the `static_pointer_cast` in your example, then check if the resulting `shared_ptr` is empty (or use or ID before the cast). Btw: don't use my naming conventions from the live example, they're just silly ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I better understand `shared_ptr` and the related. Now practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 5):

You should be storing `shared_ptr<Plant>` in your vector, not just `Plant`. With what you're currently doing, you're getting [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/13), which means that you're not actually storing `Broccoli`s, only the `Plant` portions thereof (and a cast to `Broccoli`, as you suggested at the end of your post, will not work).

Comment: Do I then need to do anything different to add to the vector or access elements from it like above?