# How to perform a dynamic_cast with a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
class BaseSession : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<BaseSession>
class DerivedSessionA : public BaseSession
class DerivedSessionB : public BaseSession
```

Within the derived class functions, I regularly call functions like this:

```
Func(boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedSessionA>(shared_from_this()));
```

Since I was working with `shared_ptr` to manage the sessions, this was working fine. Recently, I discovered that my use of `shared_ptr` is not optimal for this case. That is because these sessions are singleton objects that maintain one socket per client. If socket is reconnected, the session copies used to become zombies.

As workaround, I started passing `shared_ptr` by reference rather than copies. This solved the zombie problem.

Ideally, I felt I should be using `unique_ptr` to store the session and then pass references to other functions. That opened a whole can of worms.

How do I cast a base class `unique_ptr` object to derived class `unique_ptr` object? What is the `unique_ptr` version of the following line?

```
Func(boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedSessionA>(shared_from_this()));
```

I just want one copy of the session object, everything else should be reference.

Comment: What should happen with your pointed object if the dynamic cast fails?  Should it be deleted or do you only expect a move if the cast succeeds and never a delete?

Comment: If dynamic_cast fails, the Func gets a null object and it cancels the operation. I don't want to move, the owner should remain same.

Comment: I suspect I am looking for a weak_ptr to unique_ptr object. Short of going back to C pointer, is there any other choice?

Comment: @SharathKShetty Short answer: no. `unique_ptr` implies ownership. Weak pointers require observation logic that implies locking and refcounting. That comes at a price, which is why you need to use `shared_ptr` if you're so inclined. The good news is you can use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>` with that too (_and_ `weak_ptr`). Everybody wins.

Comment: I agree with sehe. Creating a unique_ptr that point to a resource already owned by another smart pointer without moving the resource between the two containers is wrong. A weak_ptr doesn't has the ownership of the resource pointed but a weak reference: so any operation from the weak_ptr to the unique_ptr is simply infeasible or greatly discouraged

Comment: @StefanoBuora: The resource will be owned only by unqiue_ptr, I want to do away with shared_ptr. Looks like the solution provided by Jarod42 is the best option for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unless you want to transfer ownership of your `std::unique_ptr<T>`, your function should take pointer or reference to `T`.

So signature of `Func` should be something like `Func(DerivedSessionA*)`

and then your call may look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseSession> ptr; // Initialize it with correct value

Func(dynamic_cast<DerivedSessionA*>(ptr.get()));
```

Or as you seems to call it directly from a method in `BaseSession`:

```
Func(dynamic_cast<DerivedSessionA*>(this));
```

Comment: The answer does not explain what to do if the cast fails.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` if dynamic type of this is not really a `DerivedSessionA*` (or child type).

Comment: @ChristopherPisz what to do if the cast fails depends on other context, and is the same as "what to do if a `dynamic_cast` from a raw pointer fails"

Comment: I think it will also be important to point out who owns the pointer before and after the cast, and mention unique_ptr::release vs get.

Comment: What if I do want to transfer ownership?

Comment: @aij: Other answers handle that case. But notice that is `dynamic_cast` fails, you free the resource (no owners).

Answer (score 47):

### Update

The question has been clarified:

> *sorry I was not clear. I want the ownership to remain with original owner, the called function should only get reference to it, not ownership. Not looking for two smart pointer for the same object.*

In that case, the solution is simply:

```
dynamic_cast<B&>(*my_unique_ptr)
```

**Done**. It throws if the cast doesn't succeed.

---

#### Casting `shared_ptr`

For `shared_ptr` there is `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

#### Casting `unique_ptr`

The simplest way would seem:

```
#include <memory>

struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B : A { };

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> pa(new B);

    std::unique_ptr<B> pb(dynamic_cast<B*>(pa.release())); // DO NOT DO THIS
}
```

As the commenter rightfully points out, this may leak the object if the conversion failed. That's **not** very helpful.

A reason why the `dynamic_unique_ptr_cast<>` doesn't exist might be that the `unique_ptr` type doesn't erase the deleter. It could be hard/impossible to choose an appropriate delete for the target pointer type.

However, for simple cases, you could use something like this:

```
template <typename To, typename From, typename Deleter> 
    std::unique_ptr<To, Deleter> dynamic_unique_cast(std::unique_ptr<From, Deleter>&& p) {
        if (To* cast = dynamic_cast<To*>(p.get()))
        {
            std::unique_ptr<To, Deleter> result(cast, std::move(p.get_deleter()));
            p.release();
            return result;
        }
        return std::unique_ptr<To, Deleter>(nullptr); // or throw std::bad_cast() if you prefer
    }


auto pb = dynamic_unique_cast<B>(std::move(pa));
```

Comment: I want to avoid moving the ownership of the session object. I want to pass unique_ptr by reference after the dynamic cast.

Comment: @SharathKShetty That makes zero sense. If ownership is to be shared, use shared_ptr or even a raw pointer (`dynamic_cast<B*>(p.get())`). Creating a two different smart pointers to the same object is **always a bad design smell** and asking for trouble. `unique_ptr`is precisely about transferring ownership. If you dont require it, use something else.

Comment: sorry I was not clear. I want the ownership to remain with original owner, the called function should only get reference to it, not ownership. Not looking for two smart pointer for the same object. I have mentioned that in the last line of my question.

Comment: @SharathKShetty in that case: `dynamic_cast<B&>(*my_unique_ptr)` done. It throws if the cast doesn't succeed.

Comment: Thanks @sehe. That is a nice twist to Jarad42's solution. :-)

Comment: @SharathKShetty I don't see how that's a twist. It's just doing what you want to do. Without needless complications. I've added it to my answer, just to be complete.

Comment: @Sharath I see why you say it's a twist - they're similar in intent. The difference is of course that (as said) casting the reference version will throw (`std::bad_cast`), but casting the pointer version won't (it can be null). I would argue both are appropriate, depending on how you want to handle a failed cast.

Comment: It worked in 2010, but this gives a compiler error C2440 in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You're doing something wrong (guesses: [your type is not polymorphic at all](http://rextester.com/LRZTPM83624) or [the types are not related](http://rextester.com/NCYZX35443) or [a simple mistake](http://rextester.com/LRZTPM83624)?)

Comment: I never asked you to troubleshoot my problem. I fixed my problem by taking out your code and replacing it with [common sense](http://rextester.com/YMT2386). To test your snippet, I copied pasted your code in a fresh shiny project in vc140 and it did not compile. Error C2440 definitely applies if you go look up the error.

Comment: Yeah, there's been a lot of noise coming from this post over the last two days. I tried to preserve value where possible the last time, but this discussion has gone on too long already and does not appear that it will bear fruit any time soon. Either take it to chat, or one of you can ask a new question about the problem and let a dispassionate 3rd party sort out the correct answer.

Comment: I could only get this to work by removing the `Deleter` template parameter completely, since `default_delete<From>` would not convert to `default_delete<To>`. But that's the "simple case" I was interested in anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Danra this might actually shed light for others who ran into similar cases before, which I wasn't aware of. If you have a minimal example you can add it to the answer in case it helps

Comment: @sehe Do you have a working example of the above code as-is? If so can you please share it so I can see what I did differently? If not I suggest you just amend your answer and remove the `Deleter` template parameter completely, was still helpful for me and probably for 99% of other users looking to do this for the simple case.

Comment: @Sharath Sure. It's literally the code from the answer pasted together: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed344ba1e80d54d9 - I donot like making the code less precise unless I know what problem that's solving. I'm also willing to find out there are compiler issues/library implementation issues to avoid, but right now I can only say that the code with deleter is correct and strictly more generic. I'm certainly hoping to see the problem demonstrated. If you can modify the code such that it fails on your platform, I'd happy to know the platform that it fails on.

Answer (score 3):

This is dynamic_pointer_cast of boost. The idea is quite simple(but ignore the deleter).

```
//dynamic_pointer_cast overload for std::unique_ptr
template<class T, class U> std::unique_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( std::unique_ptr<U> && r ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
{
    (void) dynamic_cast< T* >( static_cast< U* >( 0 ) );

    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( boost::has_virtual_destructor<T>::value, "The target of dynamic_pointer_cast must have a virtual destructor." );

    T * p = dynamic_cast<T*>( r.get() );
    if( p ) r.release();
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( p );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply get the stored pointer using the `std::unique_ptr<>::get()` method:

```
Func(dynamic_cast<DerivedSessionA*>(shared_from_this().get()))
```

that if `shared_from_this()` has that prototype:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseSession>& shared_from_this();
```

Comment: But shared_from_this() always returns a shared_ptr, not unique_ptr.