# Correct way to cast using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm trying to compile the following code but I get this error:

**error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr' to 'unique_ptr'**

What I'm trying to do is create a smart pointer that wraps some objects and then use them as listeners.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Table {

  public:
    struct Listener{ 
      virtual void handle(int i) = 0;
    };

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Listener>> listeners_;

    void add_listener(std::unique_ptr<Listener> l){
      listeners_.push_back(l);
    }

};


struct EventListener: public Table::Listener {
  void handle(int e){  
    std::cout << "Something happened! " << e << " \n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Table table;
  std::unique_ptr<EventListener> el;
  table.add_listener(el);

  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciate!

Comment: This won't necessarily fix your issue, but unique pointers should be moved not copied.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11002641/3093378

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) cannot be copied, only moved : you can use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Table {

  public:
    struct Listener{ 
      virtual void handle(int i) = 0;
    };

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Listener>> listeners_;

    void add_listener(std::unique_ptr<Listener> l){
      listeners_.push_back(std::move(l));
    }

};


struct EventListener: public Table::Listener {
  void handle(int e){  
    std::cout << "Something happened! " << e << " \n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Table table;
  std::unique_ptr<EventListener> el;
  table.add_listener(std::move(el));

  return 0;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c93e374190b1436)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no copy constructor for unique_ptr

From cppreference.com:

"Copy construction is disabled for objects of type unique_ptr (see move constructors, 6 and 7)."

You have to move it explicitly, or extract raw pointer and copy it around