# Create reference to object in unique_ptr with typecast

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, unique-ptr

I find I still do an embarrassingly large number of things in c style, so I am now trying to embrace the new millennium by reducing my usage of raw pointers. I have a vector of `unique_ptr<BaseClass>`, that each points to an object of a derived class. I am trying to get a nice way to refer to one of the objects of the derived class. At the moment, I do this by using the `.get()` function and casting this to the derived class.

However, as I understand it, `.get()` is mostly there to interface with legacy code that insists on raw pointers, and its use should be avoided. Having another pointer to an object within a `unique_ptr` doesn't seem like great style if it can be avoided. Is there a way to get a reference to the derived class object, without using get? Or some other convenient way of handling the object?

Here is a simplified code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Fruit {
public:
    double size = 0;
    virtual ~Fruit() = default;
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
public:
    bool hasLeaf = false;
};

void doAppleStuff(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit> > &apples) {

    // assume we know that element [0] exists and it is definitely of type Apple
    auto apple = static_cast<Apple *> (apples[0].get());  // is there a better option?

    if (apple->hasLeaf) {
        std::cout << "We can leaf now" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "We are pitiably leafless" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit> > fruitVec;
    auto apple = new Apple;
    apple->hasLeaf = true;
    std::unique_ptr<Fruit> applePt(apple);
    fruitVec.push_back(std::move(applePt));
    doAppleStuff(fruitVec);
    return 0;
}
```

(I think that it's probably possible to shorten the main function with `make_unique` from c++14).

Would it be good coding style to do something like this?

```cpp
auto &apple = *static_cast<Apple *> (apples[0].get());
```

The answer at ["Downcasting" unique_ptr<Base> to unique_ptr<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived) outlines a method to "cast" the `unique_ptr` by releasing it and recreating a new `unique_ptr` to the derived class, but that doesn't seem applicable here, as I don't really want to mess with the vector of unique pointers (unless I am missing something).

Comment: As `Fruit` has no virtual destructor, your code is currently UB.

Comment: If you insist on storing classes using pointer to base class then you need to declare some virtual methods (especially destructor) and call them instead of upcasting.

Comment: @Jarod42 Excellent point... I will edit the code to add a virtual destructor

Comment: And once you use polymorphism, virtual method and visitor would allow to avoid manual casting.

Comment: I would prefer not to create virtual methods in the base class, because I don't want the base class to know about methods that are specific to the derived class. Most of the rest of the code deals with base class objects in a polymorphic manner, but this section of code is really specific to only one derived class and methods that only this particular derived class has.

Comment: A large part of the complication in your code stems from `hasLeaf` being a member of the derived type held as the base type. As such you always must cast it (typically you would prefer a `dynamic_cast` to at least fall apart in a more controlled way in case your assumption fails). You should revisit your class design, and more generally your code. I mean doing apple stuff with a bunch of fruit does not seem very intuitive.

Comment: To avoid to add too many virtual method in base class, you might use [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @midor I get what you are saying, and it would certainly be easier if it were a vector of `Fruit`. However, the code I am using does lots of other stuff polymorphically with `Fruit` objects, with different derived classes. But there is one section that only runs if we are dealing with `Apple`s, with methods that only make sense for an `Apple`. It's quite possible that my design is not optimal, and the logic that is `Apple` specific could be folded into the `Apple` class, but it's not immediately clear to me. For now, I am stuck with casting to an `Apple`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Very interesting... thank you. I'll have to do some thinking to see if that is a good fit.

Comment: I have been there; as @Jarod42 says you can check if virtual methods and/or visitor help. CRTP is typically also something to look into. Also read up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002641/dynamic-casting-for-unique-ptr#11002936 on why dynamic casting unique pointers may be complicated.

Comment: @midor Goodness gracious... I am once again reminded of the gulf between someone who knows some c++ and an expert. Thanks for the links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the pointer is non-`nullptr`, a simpler cast is:

```
auto& apple = static_cast<Apple&>(*apples[0]);
```

This syntax works with all smart-pointers that support `T& operator*() const` (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `boost::intrusive_ptr`).

In cases with multiple inheritance casting *from-base-reference-to-derived-reference* is faster than casting *from-base-pointer-to-derived-pointer* because the latter must always check for `nullptr` before adding or subtracting an offset to the pointer (so that `nullptr` turns into `nullptr` after the cast), whereas references cannot be `nullptr` and therefore no run-time check is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A safer alternative is to define a helper function

```
template <typename T> // 
std::vector<T *> of_type(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>> & fruits) {
    std::vector<T *> result;
    for (auto & ptr : fruits) {
        if (T * item = dynamic_cast<T *>(ptr.get())) {
            result.push_back(item);
        }            
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then change `doAppleStuff` to

```
void doAppleStuff(std::vector<Apple *> & apples);
```

called as

```
doAppleStuff(as_type<Apple>(fruitVec));
```